# Responsive div's fitting to the height of the parent container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to enable 3 boxes to fill the height of its responsive container, I have looked at numerous tutorials over the web and nothing seems to be helping out.

The test site is live here to take a look:http://pagedev.co.uk/bowmite/

I just want the 3 top white boxes of latest projects to fit the height of their container. I think it looks untidy with them all different heights.

If you need any other info let me know.

Below is my html:

```
<!-- 3 latest Projects -->
<div class="home-projects">
    <!-- One Project -->
    <div class="home-project-item">
        <img class="home-project-image" src="images/postimage.jpg">
        <div class="home-project-copy">
            <p>Our experienced team of fully certified engineers regularly work on projects in excess of £4m in value, often working alongside main contractors on entire new build estates or prestige new buildings as you can see in our projects pages.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- One Project -->
    <div class="home-project-item">
        <img class="home-project-image" src="images/postimage.jpg">
        <div class="home-project-copy">
            <p>Based in Essex, our focus is across London and within the M25, working for some of the leading construction companies in the country. Our growing reputation is such that many of our contracts are repeat business from our long established clients.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- One Project -->
    <div class="home-project-item">
    <img class="home-project-image" src="images/postimage.jpg">
        <div class="home-project-copy">
            <p>BEMs highly experienced workforce are fully qualified and certified. All of our operatives hold up to date CSCS cards and company accreditations include NICEIC, Gas Safe, Construction Line, SSIP and CHAS.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.home-projects  {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.home-project-item  {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:31.333%;
    margin-right:3%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;

    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
}

.home-project-item:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right:0%;
}

.home-project-image {
    width:100%;

    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.home-project-copy  {
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

Comment: you could add a `min-height:400px;` to `.home-project-item` but I do not know how this plays out in a responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding:

```
height: 10em;
```

to .home-project-copy this gives them all the same height.

Answer (score 0):

If old browsers support is not intented go with the flexbox.

In your case only adding `display: flex` to `.home-projects` will make it work as you expect:

```
.home-projects {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   display: flex;
}
```

More info on Flexbox here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

I just added min-height:360px to the box and then on the media queries did min-height:inherit;